# The trigger compiled but fail while insert occurs, unintentional recursive

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

the Error report -
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "HW4.TR1", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HW4.TR1'
ORA-06512: at "HW4.TR1", line 8
the code:

```
 CREATE TABLE PIERS(
PID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
NAME VARCHAR2(1),
CAPACITY NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL,
TYPE VARCHAR2(20) UNIQUE,
TOTAL_SHIPS NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE SHIPS(
SID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
NAME VARCHAR2(3),
COUNTRY VARCHAR(20),
CARGO_WIEGHT NUMBER(5,0) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE DOCKING(
SID NUMBER,
PID NUMBER,
ARRIVAL_DATE DATE, 
DEPARTURE_DATE DATE,

CONSTRAINT FK_SID_DOCKING FOREIGN KEY (SID) REFERENCES SHIPS(SID),
CONSTRAINT FK_PID_DOCKING FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES PIERS(PID),
CONSTRAINT PK_DOCKING PRIMARY KEY (SID, PID, ARRIVAL_DATE, DEPARTURE_DATE)
);

INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(1, 'A', 30000, 'agricultual exports',0);  
INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(2, 'B', 30000, 'timber',0);
INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(3, 'C', 30000, 'metals',0);
INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(4, 'D', 30000, 'sling',0);
INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(5, 'E', 60000, 'Panamax',0);
INSERT INTO PIERS VALUES(6, 'F', 30000, 'bulk',0);

INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(11, 'S1', 'China', 30000);  
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(22, 'S2', 'Zimbabwe', 25000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(33, 'S3', 'Guatemala', 15000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(44, 'S4', 'China', 25000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(55, 'S5', 'Marshall Islands', 20000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(66, 'S6', 'Russia', 20000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(77, 'S7', 'Malta', 45000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(88, 'S8', 'Panama', 50000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(99, 'S9', 'Malta', 15000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(1010, 'S10', 'Marshall Islands', 20000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(1111, 'S11', 'Liberia', 25000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(1212, 'S12', 'Liberia', 15000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(1313, 'S13', 'Zimbabwe', 20000);
INSERT INTO SHIPS VALUES(1414, 'S14', 'Panama', 55000);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR1 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON DOCKING 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (TO_DATE(NEW.ARRIVAL_DATE) <= TO_DATE(NEW.DEPARTURE_DATE))
DECLARE 
cap PIERS.CAPACITY%TYPE; 
car SHIPS.CARGO_WIEGHT%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
SELECT CAPACITY INTO cap FROM PIERS WHERE PIERS.PID=:NEW.PID; 
SELECT CARGO_WIEGHT INTO car FROM SHIPS WHERE SHIPS.SID=:NEW.SID;
IF(car<= cap) THEN
    INSERT INTO DOCKING VALUES(:NEW.SID, :NEW.PID, TO_DATE(:NEW.ARRIVAL_DATE), TO_DATE(:NEW.DEPARTURE_DATE)); 
END IF;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL; 
END; 
/

INSERT INTO DOCKING VALUES(88, 5, '15-AUG-17', '15-AUG-17');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538378/maximum-number-of-recursive-sql-levels-50-exceeded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger says: "If somebody inserts a row into DOCKING I will insert yet another row into DOCKING". Thus trigger sees second insert and inserts third row.... thus sees third insert and inserts fourth...... And this music would be non-stop until ORA-00036...

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: @MorGoren correct the trigger to  do the insert once.

Comment: You can bring some sense into this. What you're trying to do at all? It looks like you wish to add some consistency check, but if so, you should not insert correct records (it would be done authomatically) but you should reject incorrect data (use something like if car > cap then raise_application_error(-20100, 'This docking cant be done');